Submittng django formwizard data to an API
I'm needing to prevent browser from progressing to next screen if any errors occur during data submission to an API. Preferably displaying a message to the user.
In the done() I've tried to return to the last step:
I have tried raising validation errors, results in validation error display on debug screen.
Redirecting to the last step, resulting lost form data and last step displaying as first
I attempted submitting data using process_step() if last step, just fails horribly.
This has been very difficult to search and likely a fundamental I'm missing.
Below is the closest i can get with done()
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    # form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

    response: DocumentResponse = add_admission(
        name_last=form_data[0]["name_last"],
        name_first=form_data[0]["name_first"],
        name_middle=form_data[0]["name_middle"],
        date_of_birth=form_data[0]["date_of_birth"],
        ssn=form_data[0]["ssn"],
        sex=form_data[1]["sex"],
        smoker=form_data[1]["smoker"],
        veteran=form_data[1]["veteran"],
        addr_street=form_data[2]["addr_street"],
        addr_street2=form_data[2]["addr_street2"],
        addr_city=form_data[2]["addr_city"],
        addr_state=form_data[2]["addr_state"],
        addr_zip=form_data[2]["addr_zip"],
        phone_mobile=form_data[3]["phone_mobile"],
        phone_home=form_data[3]["phone_home"],
        is_disabled=form_data[1]["disabled"],
    )

    if response.success:
        if not isinstance(response, AdmissionResponse):
            raise Exception("Invalid DocumentResponse Returned.")

        admission_response: AdmissionResponse = response
        client_id = admission_response.client_id
        triage = Screening.objects.get(name="Triage Risk")
        Assignment.objects.create(client_id=client_id, screening=triage)
        self.request.session["client_id"] = client_id
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("client-screenings"))
    else:
        print("We gotta redirect to the last step w/ data")


I guess the best approach would be to not refresh the page until the api has returned the response.Also if you are using a form you can check form.is_valid() if not return form.errors in response data as  if form.is_valid():             # Perform your logic with valid data             data = form.cleaned_data             return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)         else:             # Return form errors as JSON response             return Response(form.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

As hacky as it feels, I was able to achieve desired result by revisiting the process_steps() idea, manually adding a message and rending the last form.
def process_step(self, form):
    if self.steps.current == "3":

        step_form_data = form.cleaned_data
        step_data = self.get_all_cleaned_data()
        step_data.update(step_form_data)

        print(step_data)

        response: DocumentResponse = add_admission(
            name_last=step_data["name_last"],
            name_first=step_data["name_first"],
            name_middle=step_data["name_middle"],
            date_of_birth=step_data["date_of_birth"],
            ssn=step_data["ssn"],
            sex=step_data["sex"],
            smoker=step_data["smoker"],
            veteran=step_data["veteran"],
            addr_street=step_data["addr_street"],
            addr_street2=step_data["addr_street2"],
            addr_city=step_data["addr_city"],
            addr_state=step_data["addr_state"],
            addr_zip=step_data["addr_zip"],
            phone_mobile=step_data["phone_mobile"],
            phone_home=step_data["phone_home"],
            is_disabled=step_data["disabled"],
        )

        if response.success:
            # if not isinstance(response, AdmissionResponse):
            #     raise Exception("Invalid DocumentResponse Returned.")

            admission_response: AdmissionResponse = response
            client_id = admission_response.client_id
            triage = Screening.objects.get(name="Triage Risk")
            Assignment.objects.create(fcc_id=client_id, screening=triage)
            self.request.session["client_id"] = client_id

        else:
            messages.warning(self.request, response.message)
            self.render_goto_step("3")
            return

    return super().process_step(form)

